# Replacing "NA" and blanks by either similuating data or using blanks

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to php and MYSQL so this is probably a very simple thing for a lot of people but is taking me hours.

My developer created the below code which is used to parse a csv file into some MYSQL tables.

Once the data is parsed into the MYSQL table, I have a separate script which I use to create some search forms on the data.  For example, users can select all data where column X is between -50 and +50.

I want to accomplish 2 things:

1. In instances where there is either a "NA" or blank in the csv file for a particular column, I want this NOT be recognized as 0 in the database, which is what is currently happening.  For example, if I run a search where I select all values to be between -10 and 10 for column A and column A contains blanks or "NAs", then these blanks or "NAs" should not be recognized in the search output (and database) as 0s. However, they should show up in every search result. Regardless, in the search form, I do not want to see the "NAs".  I am sure I am not the first problem to encounter this problem and that there is a best practices method for this.
2. I want to replace all instances of " in the csv file with a blank. I know I can use the "preg_replace" function for this but I don't know the best place to put it.

Thanks!

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
$global_start = microtime(true);
include_once('db.php');
$full_path = @dirname(__FILE__) . '/';
$distinct_fields = array('g', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 'y', 'z', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 't', 'u', 'v');


if (isset($_POST['truncate'])) {
    mysqli_query($mysqli, 'TRUNCATE TABLE odesk_nj_data');
    mysqli_query($mysqli, 'TRUNCATE TABLE odesk_nj_catalog');
}
if (isset($_POST['filename']) && is_file($full_path . $_POST['filename'])) {
    $separator = $_POST['separator'];
    $handle = fopen($full_path . $_POST['filename'], "r");
    $fields = array();
    $i = 0;
    $proccess_iteration = 0;
    mysqli_autocommit($mysqli, false);
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $separator)) !== FALSE) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            $fields = $data;
        } elseif ($data[0] != '') {
            $branch_id = GetBranchId($data[0]);
            $qs = 'INSERT INTO odesk_nj_data SET branch_id=' . $branch_id;
            foreach ($fields as $index => $field_name) 
            {
                if (strtolower($field_name) != 'a' /*&& strtolower($field_name)!='ad'*/) 
                {
                    $tmp = explode(',', $data[$index]);
                    // if ($data[$index] == '' || $data[$index] == 'NA') 
                    // {
                        // $value = -1000.99;
                    // } 
                    // elseif (count($tmp) == 2 && is_numeric($tmp[0]) && is_numeric($tmp[1])) 
                    if (count($tmp) == 2 && is_numeric($tmp[0]) && is_numeric($tmp[1])) 
                    {
                        $value = implode('.', $tmp);
                    } else {
                        $value = $data[$index];
                    }
                    $qs .= ', `' . strtolower($field_name) . '`="' . $value . '"';
                }
                if (in_array(strtolower($field_name), $distinct_fields)) {
                    SaveToCatalog(strtolower($field_name), $value);
                }
            }
            mysqli_query($mysqli, $qs);
        }
        $i++;
        $proccess_iteration++;
        if ($proccess_iteration > 300) {
            mysqli_commit($mysqli);
            $proccess_iteration = 0;
            mysqli_autocommit($mysqli, false);
        }
    }
    mysqli_commit($mysqli);
    echo 'Upload Complete! Was uploaded ' . ($i - 1) . ' rows.';
    exit;
}

function SaveToCatalog($FieldName, $Value)
{
    global $mysqli;
    static $data;
    if (!isset($data[$FieldName])) {
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM odesk_nj_catalog WHERE field="' . $FieldName . '" ');
        while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $data[$FieldName][base64_encode($item['field_value'])] = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isset($data[$FieldName][base64_encode($Value)])) {
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM odesk_nj_catalog WHERE field="' . $FieldName . '" AND field_value="' . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $Value) . '"');
        $info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if (isset($info['id']) && $info['id'] > 0) {
            $data[$FieldName][base64_encode($Value)] = true;
        } else {
            mysqli_commit($mysqli);
            mysqli_autocommit($mysqli, true);
            $qs = 'INSERT INTO odesk_nj_catalog SET field="' . $FieldName . '", field_value="' . $Value . '"';
            mysqli_query($mysqli, $qs);
            if (mysqli_insert_id($mysqli) > 0) {
                $data[$FieldName][base64_encode($Value)] = true;
            }
            mysqli_autocommit($mysqli, false);
        }
    }
}

function GetBranchId($BranchName)
{
    global $mysqli;
    static $branches;
    if (empty($companies)) {
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM odesk_nj_branches ');
        while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $branches[$item['branch_name']] = $item['branch_id'];
        }
    }
    if (!isset($branches[$BranchName])) {
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM odesk_nj_branches WHERE branch_name="' . $BranchName . '"');
        $company_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if (isset($company_info['branch_id']) && $company_info['branch_id'] > 0) {
            $branches[$BranchName] = $company_info['branch_id'];
        } else {
            mysqli_commit($mysqli);
            mysqli_autocommit($mysqli, true);
            $qs = 'INSERT INTO odesk_nj_branches SET branch_name="' . $BranchName . '"';
            mysqli_query($mysqli, $qs);
            $branches[$BranchName] = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
            mysqli_autocommit($mysqli, false);
        }
    }
    return $branches[$BranchName];
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="nj_load.php">
    Filename to parse: <input type="text" name="filename" value="Table.csv"><br/>
    CSV Separator: <input type="text" name="separator" value=","><br/>
    Truncate Table before parsing: <input type="checkbox" name="truncate" checked=""><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Parse">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This sounds like a work request.  Not exactly what SO is for, though there is a jobs section if your developer is MIA.

Comment: As much as I'd hate to say this, you might want to consider getting  a new developer. The code doesn't escape the user input and injects them directly to the SQL queries without no sanitization whatsoever. You should be using prepared statements instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `NULL` instead of "NA", and then a numeric column.   `UPDATE table SET col1=NULL where col1='NA'`
2. After import, `UPDATE table SET col1=NULL where col1=''`.  Otherwise, i don't really know what the difference between '' and a blank is.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot.  How would I change this:

UPDATE table SET col1=NULL where col1='NA'

So that it refers to ALL columns?

Comment: keep running that query once for each column.